# When running sonarqube java dockerised app it get error sonarqube url not reachable

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am running sonarqube from docker and it's working great for local projects, but when running it manually on a dockerized app it gives

```
[ERROR] SonarQube server [http://my-external-server-url:9000] can not be reached.
```

I ran it with maven in DEBUG mode and I got that

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project MY-PROJECT: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: No route to host (Host unreachable) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project MY-PROJECT: Unable to execute SonarQube
```

Am I missing something here ??
P.S. It's a dockerized java project so I'm running from inside the docker, unlike other php projects

Comment: Maybe you should file a bug report instead of asking a question here.

Comment: What have you investigated? Did you have a look at the log files?